# Getting Service error in Sitefinity project

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, telerik, sitefinity

I am getting following error while trying to access sitefinity forms service to fetch form entries. Any one please help.

The issue not persistent, Once i recycle the application pool, it starts working. But again after some time it comes back.

```
[KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) +11165993
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Utilities.TypeConverters.TypeResolutionService.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +1141
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.WcfHelpers.WcfContext.get_ItemType() +138
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.WcfHelpers.DynamicFieldsDataContractSurrogate.GetDataContractType(Type type) +15
   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSurrogateCaller.GetDataContractType(IDataContractSurrogate surrogate, Type type) +35
   System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractExporter.GetSurrogatedType(Type type) +1904466
   System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractExporter.GetSchemaTypeName(Type type) +40
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterDataContractMessageFormatter.ValidateType(Type parameterType, IDataContractSurrogate surrogate, IEnumerable`1 knownTypes) +214
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterDataContractMessageFormatter..ctor(OperationDescription operation, Type parameterType, Boolean isRequestFormatter, Boolean useJsonFormat, DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior dcsob) +385
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.CreateXmlFormatter(OperationDescription operation, Type type, Boolean isRequestFormatter, UnwrappedTypesXmlSerializerManager xmlSerializerManager) +73
   System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.GetReplyDispatchFormatter(OperationDescription operationDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint) +377
   System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) +1766
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Utilities.MS.ServiceModel.Web.WebHttpBehavior2.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) +29
   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost) +3292
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime() +65
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnBeginOpen() +34
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +49
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +308
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open() +36
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +90
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +598

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/Sitefinity/Services/Forms/FormsService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The given key was not present in the dictionary..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +485948
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +174
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +6
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129
```

Comment: Can we see the code you're using to query the service?